# Vowpal Wabbit: How to use --interactions while using --keep and --ignore

Tags: data-science, vowpalwabbit

I create a namespace for every feature I have so a line in my vw format file looks like:

```
1 |A A:0.00649797025326 |B B_09e6fb92eadea53ec206e05e4aea5654 |C C_2171791366 |D D_830995 |E E_2082213077 |F F_830995 |G G_283.0 |H H_Firefox |I I_MacOS |J J_1 |K K_100 |L L_27079 |M M_1403.0 |N N_-1.0 |O O_-1.0 |P P_0 |Q Q_JA |R R_1403.0 |S S_-1.0 |T T_-1.0 |U U_JA |V V_desktop |W W_JP |X X_--
```

After choosing the most important features to work with (6 out of 23 features), I want to choose cross features out of the remaining features in order to improve my AUC. So for that I tried using --keep per feature for the 6 features and then using --interactions for the new examined features, but the AUC never changes, i guess because the features are not in the kept namespaces? whats the right approach here?

the command line I tried to use:

`vw train.tsv -f model.vw --loss_function logistic --hash all -l 0.01 --power_t 0.0 --noconstant --ignore 'A' --keep 'L' --keep 'P' --keep 'U' --keep 'K' --keep 'F' --keep 'W' --interactions 'BC'`

which didn't change my metrics at all. Only when using the following command line:

`vw train.tsv -f model.vw --loss_function logistic --hash all -l 0.01 --power_t 0.0 --noconstant --ignore 'A' --keep 'L' --keep 'P' --keep 'U' --keep 'K' --keep 'F' --keep 'W' --keep 'B' --keep 'C' --interactions 'BC'`

it improved the metrics.

But then because the features are in the kept namespaces, I'm not sure the metrics are improved because of the cross features and not because of adding more features.
Any suggestions?

My approach is to run with the cross features combinations until there is no more improvement in the AUC.